# getting Error Running Apache Beam with python via Dataflow runner my import is not working in dataflow it working cloudshell

Tags: python, apache-beam

apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "/home/gopalam_bhagyaraj/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1879, in  wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)] File "/home/gopalam_bhagyaraj/mealviewer/gcsaz.py", line 43, in pr2 NameError: name 'BlobServiceClient' is not defined [while running 'read-ptransform-34']

i am extracting data from azure and saving it into gcs bucket
pipline code is

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
from apache_beam.io import filesystems 
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, _BeamArgumentParser

class AzureOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
      # Use add_value_provider_argument for arguments to be templatable
      # Use add_argument as usual for non-templatable arguments
      parser.add_value_provider_argument(
          '--input_path',
          type=str,
          help='Path of the file to write')
      parser.add_value_provider_argument(
          '--value',
          type=str,
          help='Blob value')
      parser.add_value_provider_argument(
          '--table',
          type=str,
          help='azure table')
      parser.add_value_provider_argument(
          '--table_date',
          type=str,
          help='azure table date')


def run():
   def process(element):
       STORAGEACCOUNTURL = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
       STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
       CONTAINERNAME = 'xxxxxxx'
       BLOBNAME = "xxxxx_10072022.csv"
    #from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
       blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
       blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, snapshot=None)
       # with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
       blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
       data= blob_data.readall()
       writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create('gs://bkt/floder/'+ 'file2023' +'.csv')
       writer.write(data)
       writer.close()
          
   data_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(AzureOptions)
   #pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
   pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
   pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
   #pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).requirements_file = "requirements.txt"
    
   p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
   p | "gcs" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bkt/folder/config/MV.conffig') | "read" >> beam.Map(pr2)
   p.run().wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Have you tried to export your dependencies and pass them as requirements.txt while running your dataflow pipeline? Something like `python pyscript.py --requirements_file requirements.txt`

Comment: i checked the docs  it suggested to use   save_main_session true it working

Answer (score 2):

Try importing it in run()

```
def run():
   def process(element):
       from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
       STORAGEACCOUNTURL = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
       ....
```